# Motion track while knowing distance between points

Tags: tracking, motion-capture

Is there a way to 3D track points while knowing the distance between them?

Example:

I track nine points in a grid like this:

```
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

The distance between each point is 1cm exactly. Is there a way to solve camera motion with this data?

Answer (score 1):

If the tracking is accurate, and there are at least 8 good tracking points, and the camera motion contains enough parallax information to solve the scene, then yes, it is possible.

You can set the scale using known distances.

Select two trackers for which you know the distance in the real world, type that value in the **Distance** option for orientation. Then press **Apply Scale**.

[image]

Then set up the tracking scene.

Please read also the detailed post on this site on motion tracking:

[How can I get better results when doing camera motion tracking?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332)

Comment: (Sorry for late response) I do not think that you have understood my question. I watched [a video by Caption Disillusion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eKFrZNXB29M) and he said, "Knowing the exact distance between all these markers helped me extract a camera solve and recreate the move in 3D **much more precisely than could be done with auto tracking**." I was wondering how this could be done.

Comment: Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3359/camera-tracking-markers/3360#3360 **and** https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/142879/when-should-i-use-different-tracker-motion-models-when-motion-tracking/142908#142908